# I am struggling with text manipulation, please can someone explain

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image] I cant find any info on what to do next to add colour to text. I have manipulated the text by create outlines > create vector shape and > then changing to vector.

Comment: I'm afraid you may need to click the [EDIT](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/101874/edit) link under the question and add a bit more detail. I'm uncertain what you may be asking. "Create Outlines > Create vector shape > changing to vector" is really convoluted. What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/apply-colors.html

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm using CS6

In window Tab open this windows (Color, Swatches and Gradients).
These can help you in Coloring Fills and Strokes.
You can drag and drop swatches or edit colors manually RGB or CYMK.

Just take some time to see the attached samples :-)

Adding expanded adjustment
[image]

[image]

Giving fill
[image]

Giving Stroke
[image]

Gradient Fill
[image]